# Icinga2 Cluster?

Tags: icinga, icinga2

I'm trying to configure an Icinga2 Master Server with 2 Clients for the beginning. So I want the configuration like I'm configuring the Master and synchronize the Configs to the Clients.
This works already, but if a client goes down. The Master says it is still up, because the clients are checking themselves.
The tricky thing is that I can't work with IP's because all IP's are dynamic and I can't register a dyn-dns for every Server. Later it will be 30-50 Servers.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you get some solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [puppet-icinga2](https://github.com/Icinga/puppet-icinga2) which allows collecting information about nodes. On client side you'd create exportable resource (puppet code follows):

```
  @@icinga2::object::host { $::fqdn:
    display_name => $::fqdn,
    address      => $::ipaddress_eth0,
    check_command => 'hostalive',
    target        => "/etc/icinga2/zones.d/${::domain}/hosts.conf",
    zone          => $::fqdn,
  }

  @@::icinga2::object::endpoint { "$::fqdn":
      host => "$::ipaddress_eth0",
  }

  @@::icinga2::object::zone { "$::fqdn":
      endpoints => [ "$::fqdn", ],
      parent    => 'master',
  }
```

which will be propagated to master (PuppetDB is required):

```
  Icinga2::Object::Host <<| |>> { }
  Icinga2::Object::Endpoint <<| |>> { }
  Icinga2::Object::Zone <<| |>> { }
```

As long as the puppet master has stable DNS you'll have updated `zone.conf`. After `puppet agent` run on client host information gets registered in PuppetDB. Upon next `puppet agent` run on master it will have up-to-date information about the node.

Then you can implement a check from icinga master:

```
apply Service "ping" to Host {
  import "generic-service"

  check_command = "ping"
  zone = "master" //execute check from master zone
  assign where "linux-server" in host.groups
}
```

Note there are also other automation integrations like [Ansible](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2-ansible) which might offer similar functionality.